# Pra que serve o __all__ no Python?

Tags: python

Já vi alguns códigos escritos em Python cujo arquivo `__init__.py` possuia uma variável `__all__` com uma `list` atribuída.

Exemplo:

```
__all__ = ['foo', 'bar']
```

Já notei que em Python, quando as coisas começam com `underline`, significa que é alguma funcionalidade especial.

Então, eu gostaria de saber para que serve esse `__all__`?

Comment: _ as vezes não se refere a uma funcioanlidade especial, Como python não tem escopo (privado, public) eles normalmente utilizam _ para indicar attributos e método privados.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

O `__all__` deve ser uma lista de `strings` que define quais símbolos serão exportados de um módulo quando for usado **`from <module> import *`**.

Também serve pra facilitar a leitura do código. Qualquer pessoa que for ler o código fonte vai saber facilmente quais são os membros expostos publicamente deste módulo.

#### Por exemplo

Código do módulo

```
__all__ = ['foo', 'bar']

baz = 5
bar = 10
def foo(): 
    return 'qualquer coisa'
```

Na utilização

```
from module import *

print foo()
print bar

# A linha abaixo causará uma exception, porque o membro não foi exportado
print baz
```

[<sup>Coloquei o código no GitHub para referência futura</sup>](https://github.com/jfbueno/Stack-Overflow-Portugues/tree/master/Python/176527)

Se o **`__all__`** do exemplo acima for removido, todos os membros cujo nome não inicie com *underline* serão importados.

**Observação**: É importante notar que os membros citados no **`__all__`** só vão afetar o comportamento do **`import *`**. Sendo assim, os membros não citados nele continuam acessíveis por "*import* direto". No exemplo, seria possível fazer `from modulo import baz` e utilizar este valor.